# oauth 2.0 google service account google sheet api connection time out error no 110 how to solve

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

Hi i am updating Google sheet by using google service account,
google drive api and google sheet api.
initially code run succesfully  but aftet some time
returning errno110 retry exceeded

My code is

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import json
import pandas as pd

scopes = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]
credentials 
=ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name 
("client_secret1.json" 
, scopes)

file = gspread.authorize(credentials) # authenticate the JSON key 
with gspread
wb = file.open("gw_data")  
sh = wb.worksheet('dt_trial')    

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],columns = ['Date', 'Time', 
'LTP' , 'Ce', 'Pe'])

sh.update([df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist())
```

PLZZ help me i am new at coding

Error

/

> File
> "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gspread/client.py",
> line 121, in open
> self.list_spreadsheet_files(title, folder_id),   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gspread/client.py",
> line 96, in list_spreadsheet_files
> res = self.request("get", url, params=params).json()   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gspread/client.py",
> line 59, in request
> response = getattr(self.session, method)(   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
> line 555, in get
> return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py",
> line 476, in request
> self.credentials.before_request(auth_request, method, url, request_headers)   File
> "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/auth/credentials.py",
> line 133, in before_request
> self.refresh(request)   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py",
> line 410, in refresh
> access_token, expiry, _ = _client.jwt_grant(   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py",
> line 193, in jwt_grant
> response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)   File
> "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py",
> line 161, in _token_endpoint_request
> response_status_ok, response_data = _token_endpoint_request_no_throw(   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py",
> line 115, in _token_endpoint_request_no_throw
> response = request(method="POST", url=token_uri, headers=headers, body=body)   File
> "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py",
> line 189, in **call**
> six.raise_from(new_exc, caught_exc)   File "", line 3, in raise_from google.auth.exceptions.TransportError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max
> retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
> 0x7f68f5d0a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110]
> Connection timed out'))

Comment: Try checking this  https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/819

Answer (score 0):

ok i found solution
Actually i was running this code from android mobile IDE
and in my google sheet setting transfer files only over wi-fi was enabled. And i havent connected to wifi using net through sim card.
So I think bot was trying to transfer data but  wifi setting not allowing it so time out error was generated.

Now i changed the setting and code is running smoothly